# Shell script not able to trap the signal ALRM (from TMOUT)

Tags: shell

I have a text-menu like script which is used for some small operations.
And inside it there is a read command.
for e.g

```
read response
```

Now say if the script is ran and it will wait for user input. I let it stay idle and wait for the TMOUT to kick in. I just wanted to trap this signal and exit.

So I simply try:

```
trap 'exit' ALRM
read response
```

But it does not work, the script just kind of loop itself(e.g refresh this menu again)

I tried to do strace on this process when TMOUT comes, and I did see this SIGARLM, kicking in after the select subsystem call, but the script is ignoring it for some reason? 
The only thing when it worked was if I do "trap exit ERR" and not "trap exit ALRM"

Any advise please?

strace:

```
06:49:22 select(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL) = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be 
restarted if no handler)

06:49:32 --- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
06:49:32 alarm(0)                       = 0
06:49:32 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ALRM], NULL, 8) = 0
06:49:32 ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo 
...}) = 0
06:49:32 ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
06:49:32 write(1, "\n###############################"..., 327) = 327
06:49:32 write(1, "Your choice: ", 13)  = 13
06:49:32 rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x453d70, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT, 
0x7f407e998250}, {0x453d70, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT, 0x7f407e998250}, 
8) = 0
06:49:32 setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={20, 0}}, 
{it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={0, 0}}) = 0
06:49:32 rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x41a760, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT, 
0x7f407e998250}, {0x41a760, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT, 0x7f407e998250}, 
8) = 0
06:49:32 ioctl(2, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=59, ws_col=211, ws_xpixel=0, 
ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
06:49:32 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [WINCH], NULL, 8) = 0
06:49:32 ioctl(2, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
06:49:32 ioctl(2, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost -isig -icanon - 
echo ...}) = 0

06:49:32 select(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL) = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be 
restarted if no handler)

06:49:52 --- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
06:49:52 alarm(0)                       = 0
06:49:52 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ALRM], NULL, 8) = 0
06:49:52 ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo 
...}) = 0
06:49:52 ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
06:49:52 write(1, "\n###############################"..., 327) = 327
06:49:52 write(1, "Your choice: ", 13)  = 13
06:49:52 rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x453d70, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT, 
0x7f407e998250}, {0x453d70, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT, 0x7f407e998250}, 
8) = 0
06:49:52 setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={20, 0}}, 
{it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={0, 0}}) = 0
06:49:52 rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x41a760, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT, 
0x7f407e998250}, {0x41a760, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT, 0x7f407e998250}, 
8) = 0
06:49:52 ioctl(2, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=59, ws_col=211, ws_xpixel=0, 
ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
06:49:52 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [WINCH], NULL, 8) = 0
06:49:52 ioctl(2, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
06:49:52 ioctl(2, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost -isig -icanon - 
echo ...}) = 0

06:49:52 select(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL^Cstrace: Process 26653 detached
```